# Dropdown div doesn't push down the content

Tags: css

I've got a dropdown from header div which has to push down the content(e.g. when you click This is Icon it appears Blue dropdown which has to push down h1 tags).

The problem is the height of two classes(`header-bar__top, header-bar`) which I can't change and I need them to be the same height. Is there a way to do that?

I can manipulate only these classes: `.header-bar-mobile-drop-down__container, .header-bar-mobile-drop-down__item, .header-bar-mobile-drop-down__icon-button`

```css
.header-bar-mobile-drop-down__container {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header-bar-mobile-drop-down__item {
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.header-bar-mobile-drop-down__icon-button {
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.header-bar-mobile-drop-down__icon-button:focus+.header-bar-mobile-drop-down__item {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 26px;
  height: 68px;
  color: black;
  background-color: blue;
}

.header-bar {
  height: 3.5rem;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: orange;
}

.header-bar__top {
  height: 3.5rem;
  z-index: 100;
}

.header-bar__container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: 1152px;
}

.header-bar__container:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="header-bar">
    <div class="header-bar__top">
      <div class="header-bar__container">
        <div class="header-bar-mobile-drop-down__container">
          <button class="header-bar-mobile-drop-down__icon-button" tabindex="1">
                This is Icon
              </button>
          <div class="header-bar-mobile-drop-down__item">
            This is my drop down
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1>This need to be pushed down</h1>
  <h1>But instead</h1>
  <h1>The dropdown is getting overlayed</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't push the following content down, because you limited the height of the parent element(s) to 3.5em - so the dropped-down element will _overflow_ its container.

Comment: @CBroe Yeah I discovered it as well. Should I set height differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `min-height` instead of `height` on the header bar and header bar top otherwise it will stay the same height and the drop down will be show as overflow (which is why the content below doesn't move)

```css
.header-bar-mobile-drop-down__container {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header-bar-mobile-drop-down__item {
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.header-bar-mobile-drop-down__icon-button {
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.header-bar-mobile-drop-down__icon-button:focus+.header-bar-mobile-drop-down__item {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 26px;
  height: 68px;
  color: black;
  background-color: blue;
}

.header-bar {
  min-height: 3.5rem;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: orange;
}

.header-bar__top {
  min-height: 3.5rem;
  z-index: 100;
}

.header-bar__container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: 1152px;
}

.header-bar__container:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="header-bar">
    <div class="header-bar__top">
      <div class="header-bar__container">
        <div class="header-bar-mobile-drop-down__container">
          <button class="header-bar-mobile-drop-down__icon-button" tabindex="1">
            This is Icon
          </button>
          <div class="header-bar-mobile-drop-down__item">
            This is my drop down
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1>This need to be pushed down</h1>
  <h1>But instead</h1>
  <h1>The dropdown is getting overlayed</h1>
</div>
```

If you can't change the height of the two classes, then I would move the drop down outside the header and use a checkbox toggle instead:

```css
.header-bar-mobile-drop-down__container {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header-bar-mobile-drop-down__icon-button {
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#dropdown-toggle {
  display: none;
}

.header-bar-mobile-drop-down__item {
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 68px;
  color: black;
  background-color: blue;
}

#dropdown-toggle:checked+.header-bar-mobile-drop-down__item {
  display: block;
}

.header-bar {
  height: 3.5rem;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: orange;
}

.header-bar__top {
  height: 3.5rem;
  z-index: 100;
}

.header-bar__container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: 1152px;
}

.header-bar__container:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="header-bar">
    <div class="header-bar__top">
      <div class="header-bar__container">
        <div class="header-bar-mobile-drop-down__container">
          <label for="dropdown-toggle" class="header-bar-mobile-drop-down__icon-button" tabindex="1">
            This is Icon
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input id="dropdown-toggle" type="checkbox">
  <div class="header-bar-mobile-drop-down__item">
    This is my drop down
  </div>
  <h1>This need to be pushed down</h1>
  <h1>But instead</h1>
  <h1>The dropdown is getting overlayed</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I've also added an alternate way to doing it if you need fixed heights - see edit

Comment: I am wondering if your second offer will work in the VUE framework, that is actually a better way of doing it for me

Comment: It should do - after all it's only css and html

Comment: Just a question, wondering why we need  <input id="dropdown-toggle" type="checkbox"> as well?

Comment: it's for the style to show the drop down when it's checked: `#dropdown-toggle:checked+.header-bar-mobile-drop-down__item ` - I changed your icon button to be a label that targets that checkbox - [this is an example tutorial](https://tutorialzine.com/2015/08/quick-tip-css-only-dropdowns-with-the-checkbox-hack)